# WAG matrix implementation

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, phylogeny

I am working with certain programs in **python3.4**. I want to use **WAG matrix** for phylogeny inference, but I am confused about the formula implemented by it.

For example, in phylogenetics study, when a sequence file is used to generate a distance based matrix, there is a formula called "**p-distance**" implemented and on the basis of this formula and some standard values for sequence data, a matrix is generated which is later used to construct a tree. When a character based method for tree construction is used, "WAG" is one of the matrices used for likelihood tree construction. What I want to say is that if one wants to implement this matrix, then what is the formula basis for it?
I want to write codes for this implementation. But first I need to understand the logic used by WAG matrix.

> I have an aligned protein sequence file and I need to generate "WAG"
>   matrix from it. The thing is that I have been studying literature
>   regarding wag matrix but I could not get how does it perform
>   calculation??? Does it have a specific formula?? (For example,
>   'p-distance' is a formula used bu distance matrix) I want to give
>   aligned protein sequence file as input and have a matrix generated as
>   output.